# Spotify API: Restricting recommendations to specific artists?

Tags: python, spotify, spotipy

I'm working on an app using the Spotipy library and would like to use the Spotify recommendations call to get recommended songs by only a specific artist. I know there are tuneable attributes for more specific characteristics but is there a parameter/argument that would allow you to restrict the results by artists? Scoured the docs and couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would require access to the underlying representation of tracks/artists (to be able to compute similarity with specific input artists as you'd like, for example) used in Spotify's own recommender models, which is unfortunately not public.

As a workaround, something you could try is to leverage the seeds in the Recommendation endpoint, and add to these some tracks from the desired artist in the hope that this will also steer recommendations toward the artist.